# PHP in_array function not working with mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

If I do not use MySQL, the PHP **in_array** function works as expected. In this example, the *if* statement would execute and display *the array contains the keyword blue* because the **in_array** function is able to find keyword *blue* in the array.

```
<?php
$keyword = "blue";
$array = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");

if (in_array($keyword, $array)) {echo "the array contains keyword $keyword";}
else {echo "the array does not contain keyword $keyword";}
?>
```

**in_array** fails to do the same when selecting *red, green, blue, yellow* from MySQL. In this example, if I echo $array, *red green blue yellow* is displayed in the Web browser, so I know *blue* is in the $array variable. However, the *else* statement executes and displays *the array does not contain keyword blue*.

```
<?php
$keyword = "blue";

$con = new mysqli('domain','username','password','database');
$sql = "select * from colors";
$sql_query = $con->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
  $array = $row['colors'];

  if (in_array($keyword, $array)) {echo "the array contains keyword $keyword";}
  else {echo "the array does not contain keyword $keyword";}
}
?>
```

If anyone has any tips or suggestions here, I certainly would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I am able to successfully get the "if" statement to trigger with array_key_exists when not using MySQL.  However, array_key_exists is still causing the "else" statement to trigger when getting the $array using MySQL.  Thanks for the suggestion here! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SQL version you get a record where a field named `colors` should exist.
But this field contains a string (maybe a comma-separated list, something like `blue,red,...`), *not an array*.

So when you execute `in_array($keyword, $array)` you fire a PHP error (but likely you have not currently error_report set to show them).

What you *must* do is to transform the content you got in `colors` field into an array.
In the case it is like evoked above:

```
$array = explode(',', $row['colors']);
```

Or whatever appropriate depending on what is exactly the `colors` field structure.

Comment: oh I saw references to explode before but I didn't recognize this as the way to handle this situation.  Wow, I really appreciate this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I used this answer. And it still works perfectly.

If you have an array with only values you should use in_array function as this example:

```
$array = array("A", "B", "C");
in_array($string, $array) ? "found" : "not found";
```

If you have an array with keys you should use isset function as this example:

```
$array = array("A" => "Result A", "B" => "Result B", "C" => "Result C");
isset($array[$string]) ? "found" : "not found";
or like:
if(isset($array[$string])) { do your stuff... }
```